# Как вызвать метод в компоненте Vue после обновления vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

В хуке created вызывается метод, который подгружает данные в стор. На основании полученных данных необходимо вызвать еще один метод, но если вызывать его в хуках, то стор все еще undefined, следовательно, второй метод возвращает ошибку. Поведение логичное, понимаю, но как быть в данной ситуации? Подгрузить данные нужно до рендера.

Есть еще одна связанная проблема. Первый метод может обрабатываться чуть дольше, чем хотелось бы (это запрос к бд), и тогда страница может отрендериться пустой.

Comment: Прикрепите пример вашего кода для наглядности.

Comment: Если метод завязан на данных, может использовать watch ?